# Same material being used on two objects coming up different please help?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm using a really simple texture on two different items but they're coming out different shades how do I get them to be the same colour?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your Normals area all pointing the right way.

Comment: Silly question... just in case .. does it matter that the _Brightness Contrast_ node is not connected in the illustrated tree?